# Unable to run PowerShell script in Windows 2008 R2 Standard which is installed by Vagrant

Tags: windows, powershell, vagrant

I am unable to run this PowerShell script

```
# Execute .exe file

 Get-ChildItem "C:\vagrant" -Filter *.exe | Where Name -NotMatch '.*NoDB\.exe$' | % {
New-Object psobject -Property @{
No = [int]([regex]::Match($_.Name, '(?<=CL)\d+').Value)
Name = $_.FullName
}

} | Sort No -Descending | Select -ExpandProperty Name -First 1 | 
Foreach { & $_ -s2 -sp"-SilentInstallation=server -UpdateMaterials=yestoall -UpgradeDBIfRequired=yes"}
```

in Windows Windows 2008 R2 Standard because

```
**********************
 Windows PowerShell Transcript Start
 Start time: 20160719080730
 Username  : VAGRANT-2008R2\vagrant 
 Machine      : VAGRANT-2008R2 (Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1) 
 **********************
 Transcript started, output file is C:\Users\vagrant\Documents\PowerShell_transc
ript.20160719080730.txt
Where-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert the "Name" 
value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock
".
At C:\vagrant\Install_Ortho.ps1:7 char:49
+ Get-ChildItem "C:\vagrant" -Filter *.exe | Where <<<<  Name -NotMatch '.*NoDB
\.exe$' | % {
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBi 
ndingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerSh 
  ell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand

 **********************
 Windows PowerShell Transcript End
 End time: 20160719080730
 **********************
```

I tried to use this advice  "Try using {} instead of parentheses around your argument." Same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax:

```
Where Property -[OperatorAsParameterName] 'value'
```

is introduced in PowerShell 3.0 - Windows 2008 R2 comes with PowerShell 2.0!

The version 2.0 equivalent would be:

```
Where {$_.Name -NotMatch '.*NoDB\.exe$'}
```

---

You may fix that one instance, but then other parts of the scripts will likely going to fail, and you have to keep fixing version 3.0 syntax until you've rewritten the entire thing

I would recommend finding a 2008R2-specific version of Vagrant, or filing this finding as a compatibility bug with their development team

Comment: +1 but PowerShell 2.0 does support `-First`, it just doesn't optimize the pipeline by stopping it (it still processes all items, but only passes the first X down the line). Demonstration: run this in 2 vs 3+: `1,2,3,4,5 | % { $_ | Write-Verbose -Verbose ; $_ } | select -f 2`